# Read file if Validator is successful

Tags: php, oop

I would like to read a text file in my index.php with the object-oriented way.

The file lies in the Reports folder. The validator should first see if there is a file...

If that is the case, the file should be loaded (read). 
But I can not handle it. I do not know how to get my file from the validator into the index.php

**Index.php**

```
<?php

use Validator\Validator;

require_once('Validator/Validator.php');

$validator = new Validator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Reports/file.txt');

// load file.txt and handle error by Validator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

Prepend the document root into your file path when you create a new instance of the Validator:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Reports/file.txt';
}
```

Or you can pass a parameter to your constructor.

```
public function __construct($path){
    $this->path = $path;
}
```

Update the `checkFile` function to check the path of the class:

```
public function checkFile(){

    if(!file_exists($this->path))
        echo 'Mehp.';
    else
        echo 'Yay.';

}
```

Then initialize the Validator with the right path:

```
$validator = new Validator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Reports/file.txt');
$validator->checkFile();
```

### Option 2

You can remove the `$path` variable from the `Validator` class completely.

```
class Validator{
    public function checkFile($path){
        if(!file_exists($path))
            echo 'Mehp';
        else
            echo 'Yay';
    }
}
```

Then to validate:

```
$validator = new Validator;
$validator->checkFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Reports/file.txt');
```

Comment: I don't get my success message, just a white screen

Comment: Did it. Nothing happens, hmm

Comment: @PhilTilor Did you also add the `$validator->checkFile();` and remove the `$path` from the function's parameters?